# MySQL update with subquery and give error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have one question.
I have a table `table_histories` and look like this

```
id | id_personel | nip | created_at | updated at
```

and I have another table `table_personels` look like this

```
id | nip | name | created_at | updated_at
```

I want to update the table of table_histories look like this

```
UPDATE table_histories 
SET id_personel = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table_personels 
    WHERE nip = table_histories.nip
)
```

and when I run it, it give me error

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

one data on `table_personels` can have many histories.

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: The error says that there are multiple personels with the same `nip`. Which one should be put into `table_histories`?

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result.

Comment: i want to put id from table_personels into column id_personel from table_histories

Comment: But there's more than one id. Which one should it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highest top 1 add this.

```
UPDATE table_histories 
SET id_personel = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table_personels 
    WHERE nip = table_histories.nip
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 1;
)
```

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` returns a random row from the set of matches. Use `ORDER BY` to get consistent results. Or use `SELECT MAX(id)`